# Google Maps API - How to use custom icons with text?

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

I tried the following URL:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.7|0|FFAA11|19|_|A

But it only works in Chrome, IE, surprise, does not work, the intention was to display an orange marker icon with a letter A in the middle!

I want to work in Internet Explorer, please someone help me!

I'm using IE 11.

The code is as follows:

```
var iconURL = ((selecionado != i) ? 
                'https://mts.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-a.png&text=' + String.fromCharCode(65 + l) + '&psize=16&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff333333&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1' 
                :
                'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.7|0|FFAA11|19|_|' + String.fromCharCode(65 + l)
               );

            marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: ((i >= latln.length) ? latLonEmpresa : latln[i]),
                map: map,
                icon: ((titulo[i]) ? iconURL : '')
            });
```

Comment: Could you please put up some code of what you have already tried?

Comment: There is some information here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#simple_icons

Comment: It was not necessary I post a piece of code, because the problem is the URL to test Simply copy and paste the URL in the browser, it was not necessary to post the code I did not understand why my question with marked negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I use https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.7|0|FFAA11|19|_|A 
It redirect to https and get error in IE:

---

There is a problem connecting securely to this website.

The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.

### Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.

Seem the certificate only for www.google.com
If you use: http://www.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.7|0|FFAA11|19|_|A seem working

Comment: Sorry, I put as https, but actually does not work if I by only Http.

Comment: Thank you Jason Lou  That's right, the url I was using was wrong!